# How was Domino able to be tortured when she was so lucky?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2

In *Deadpool 2* why was Domino able to be tortured when her mutant power was being 'lucky'?

I understand that most mutants don't show their powers right away, eg

[Mutant Powers](https://x-men.fandom.com/wiki/Mutants)

> The majority of mutants develop these abilities, which vary from
>   person to person, usually upon puberty, though there are some mutants
>   who display powers and/or physical mutations from birth, or in their
>   twenties. Some mutants even display abilities from within the womb and
>   posthumously, like Professor Charles Xavier and Jean Grey,
>   respectively.

And that some mutants are not able to control their powers when at this age, but Domino was sent to school for mutants and she obviously had her power and being lucky does not seem like a power that can be controlled in the first place. Was it that it was not working correctly due to her age or something else?

### What was the reason for her to be able to be tortured as a young mutant?

Comment: She needs "line of sight" according to her bio on Looper.com. Maybe they just blindfolded her?

Comment: Presumably though they just identified the x-Gene through testing and dragged her off to the orphanarium before her powers presented themselves. Probably as soon as she had the capacity to do so, she escaped.

Comment: @Valorum, That sounds like an answer. I'll up-vote it.

Comment: @Valorum That sounds odd. In the movie a bus appeared even though she didn't see it before it did.

Comment: @Parrotmaster, I think he means that if she has the ability to see anything in-line of sight that she is lucky, hence things behind her would be in-line of sight if she turned around. But , if she was blindfolded, she would only be able to the blindfold. Well thats the way I took the comment.

Comment: Probably the bio is just talking crap. Looper are not renowned for their investigative vigour

Comment: @KyloRen I very much doubt that that's how it works.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think we have an answer from the movie. But logically: **her power isn't infinite.**

Sure, she's lucky. For example, if one badguy tries to attack her, maybe he'll end up slipping on a banana peel and knocking himself out. But what if 10 badguys attack her? 100?

The answer of course depends on the needs of the plot, but the point is that her powers don't make her invulnerable from any danger without any limits.

You could also think about it in terms of long-term luck: if she hadn't been tortured, she wouldn't have been put on the path she's on. Or maybe the alternative to being tortured was somehow worse: maybe without her power, she would have been killed.

Or maybe she just didn't have her powers yet.

But in the end, we don't have an answer from the movie, so it's up to each viewer to come up with their own theories.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the movies explained this.

The comics, specifically the [one Domino series](https://www.marvel.com/comics/series/24137/domino_2018) seems particularly relevant to this though, through events shown through flashbacks.

In this continuity, Domino doesn't go to the Essex School. She was created as part of a secret government breeding program and was the only one to survive it (probably due to her power). We see that she is able to use her powers against them at least once in *Domino #3*, right on her 10th birthday. The doctors there (who she describes as being the closest thing she has to family although they treat her like a "cosmetics rat") taser her (on what seems to be the lowest albeit still painful setting) and she doesn't do anything to react.

They then give her a cat, let her get attached to it, then were going to taser it. Just before this happened, the one doctor who was allergic to cats sneezed and accidentally tasered the other doctor, which was obviously caused by Domino's powers. Because of this they brand her with a black tattoo over her eye so that she remembers what she did every time she looks in a mirror. The operation is briefly shown in *Domino #1*:

[image]

As you can see, she's restrained on the table, and it doesn't seem like luck is helping her.

---

Based on this I would say that it's *likely* that:

- The school used restraints, both physical and perhaps also drugs. (Drugs are used on her in [this other comic](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/X-Force_Vol_1_68) when Domino is taken prisoner.)
- The school threatened her with punishing others if she acted up. (I went to a regular elementary school and they would often punish everyone with something like no recess for the actions of one individual if that person didn't own up to the crime.)
- She wasn't as good with her powers then as she is now. (Like almost anything, you need practice to get better, which is why there are places like Xavier's school.)

Answer (score 1):

We don't know what form of torture Domino was subjected to, it did not have to be physical (which her luck would have probably counteracted) it might have been mental, or, if it was determined she could not be tortured directly possibly other children where tortured in her place, this in fact may have been her "luck" keeping her safe by putting others in her place. But this would be a form of torture for her.

Comment: "I finally know why I'm here. I was raised in this place. Well, not raised.I was tortured."  She literally says she was tortured there.

Comment: that torture does not have to have been physical, it may have been mental, it may have been that watching the other children suffering, not being able to do anything about it, but her ability meaning she avoided it herself was a form of torture. We don't know the context of that statement and therefore can't just assume she suffered in the same way as the others.

Comment: Your comment isn't necessarily wrong, but that's not what your answer says. You said we don't know that she was tortured, just that she lived there. Domino says right in the movie that she not only lived there, but was tortured. You can split hairs about what sort of torture she may or may not have endured, but your OP is factually wrong.

Comment: have amended my answer had a brain fart when I wrote it the first time and completely forgot the comment about her being tortured there.

Comment: Though ironically named Domino, her form of torture was having to play the game dominoes, which, even with her x gene, is not her game.

Comment: although with her X gene she would always win, always having the perfect tiles to play. I don't understand why Domino isn't living it large on an island somewhere bought with her winnings after visiting Vegas :)